# server web with redundant mariaDB databases

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, replication, high-availability

I would like like some advices on how to set up a server web in HA with a php application using virtual machines with a RED HAT linux OS. 
The idea is to have two virtual server web sharing a common document root with NFS or iSCSI plus other two MariaDB databases replicating the data.
I have some documentation to follow anyway I'd like to know your opinion in particular about how to cope with the replication of the databases which must be redundant.

Many Thanks
Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to share files.  The code does not know how to coordinate things between two instances of mysqld touching the *same* data files.

Then you talk about replication.  This involves *separate* data files.  But, if you put them on the same physical drive, what is the advantage?  If the drive crashes, you lose both.

Read more about HA solutions, and make a priority list of what things "keep you up at night".  Drive failure, motherboard failure, network corruption, floods, earthquakes, bats in the belfry, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! The main issue for me is how to allow the server web to detect the active machine in a replication between mariadb databases (I have configured two virtual machines each with a mariadb database with an active-active or active-passive repication).

Comment: That takes some 3rd party proxy server or load balancer.